# Multiple Conditional Operators mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql

How would I construct a query with the following base function

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friend_requests WHERE confirmed=1 AND (sender_id='".$user_id."' OR recipient_id='".$user_id."')");
```

Where `$user_id` is the current ID held by the session.

Comment: I don't understand, is all you want session_id? http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to call [`session_start()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) to initiate session handling on the page. And make sure to use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to protect against SQL injection. Your question is a little unclear in terms of what exactly you want from the session. If your `$user_id` variable is a value that is stored in the session, you can retrieve it from the `$_SESSION` superglobal. If `$user_id` *is* the actual session id, you can retrieve it using the [`session_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) function.

```
<?php
session_start();
// ...
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']; // or $user_id = session_id();

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friend_requests WHERE confirmed=1 AND "
    . "(sender_id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($user_id) . "' OR "
    . "recipient_id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($user_id) . "')");
// ...
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It turns out it was one of my helper functions not checking against duplicate results.